# conflicting class names in namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have a class which is not part of any namespace

class A(*) .

And I have another class with same name but part of namespace

class A part of namespace B.

In xyz.cpp, I have the below:

```
#include "..."

using namespace B;
// some code
A::var; // This A should be part of (*) and not namespace B.
// some code
```

But since I have conflicting class names, I get errors. Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

The `using namespace` keyword imports all of the names from the specified namespace into the global namespace. Since you already declared a `class A` in the global namespace, this results in a conflict.

Solution: Don't use `using namespace B`.

This is effectively what you're doing:

```
namespace GLOBAL {
    class A { ... };
};

namespace B {
    class A { ... };
};

using namespace B /* export 'B::A' into 'GLOBAL' resulting in a conflict; */ ;
```

Comment: Thanks. I used ::A::var to access the global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You may not use

```
using namespace B;
```

but use like

```
 B::A::var
```

instead.